# How to run a monitoring application?

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I want to build a simple application, which does the following:

1. Make an http call towards a specific end point.
2. If the end point doesn't respond, I want to reset a scheduled task on a remote machine (restarting the service that is exposing the end point).

But once built, how do I run such an application?

Should I make it a continuously running application, that just performs its logic every X minutes?

Should I make it a scheduled task that runs the application every X minutes?

Or is there a completely different way of doing it? If all options are viable, that's fine as well, I don't want to start a "which do you feel is better" debate. I just want to dodge any land mines I might have missed.

Comment: There is a whole bucket full of options on this one. The simplest, seems to be a Shell-Script and a corresponding cron-job.But this highly depends on your requirements and your existing environment.

Comment: @triplem isn’t crib-jobs limited to Linux/Unix? I need it to run on a Windows server.

Comment: I am not a Windows expert, but aren't there "Scheduled Tasks" or something similar?

Comment: @triplem it sounds plausible. I don’t know enough about either to say for sure . I’ll try to make it a scheduled task at see how it works out, thanks!